# What is PHImageRequestOptionsResizeMode default value?

Tags: ios, swift, phasset, photokit

What happens if I don't specify any options in  `PHImageRequestOptions`  for `resizeMode` ?

Will photos deliver the image size that I pass in `targetSize` or would it delivery exact image size ?

Documentations seems is not clearing that part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Defaults to PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeNone (or no resize)